# Error in parsing an XML file in Android

Tags: java, android, textview, xml-parsing

In my app I am trying to parse an XML file. I am able to parse it and in logcat I can find the number of tags but in my text view I am not able to view it. Now I am trying to print only one tag named as question in my text view. My text view is named `flip`.

Following is one part of my code:

```
//XML parsing happens here
            try
            {
                saxparserfactory1 = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
                saxparser1 = saxparserfactory1.newSAXParser();
                xmlreader1 = saxparser1.getXMLReader();

                inputstream1 = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.worldhistory);
                xmlreader1.setContentHandler(myXMLHandler);         
                xmlreader1.parse(new InputSource(inputstream1));                

                //getting the values of xml
                flashcards = myXMLHandler.getflashcards();
                flashcard = myXMLHandler.getflashcard();                

                try
                {
                o = flashcards.getFlashcard().size();               

                Log.e("Parsing", "flashcard size = "+o);                
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Log.e("parsing",""+e);
                }   

                String question ="" ;
                if(index1 < flashcards.getFlashcard().size())
                {
                    question  = flashcards.getFlashcard().get(q[index1]).getQuestion();
                    Log.e("", "Qustion "+question);
                    Flip1.setText(question);
                    index1++;
                }                           
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.e("",""+e);
            }
        }
```

In my logcat I am able to view the following lines

```
03-31 19:25:16.578: ERROR/MyXMLHandler(10361): Flashcard created
03-31 19:25:16.578: ERROR/Parsing(10361): flashcard size = 68
03-31 19:25:16.578: ERROR/(10361): java.lang.NullPointerException
```

The NullPointerException is been shown from the outer catch block.

Comment: If you read the log carefully, you can find the exact line number on which you are getting this error.

Comment: you're checking index1 < flashcards.getFlashcard().size() but waht about q?

Comment: @mudit - i am just getting the word NullPointerException, no other details in my logcat

Comment: @2red13 - i have mentioned q as q[]. the content inside the tags are been printed in my logcat but not in my text view....

Comment: but this term: question  = flashcards.getFlashcard().get(q[index1]).getQuestion(); seems to make the crash, i wonder if q.size < inder or getQuestions is NULL one of this are suspected

Comment: sorry guys i have added a view flipper in my text view and it is to be the problem. now i have removed the flip and its working good...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running `logcat` with `-v long`.  That should print out all available metadata ... and hopefully the full stack trace.

You also need to call the three argument version of [`Log.e`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html#e%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Throwable%29) method something like this:

```
    Log.e("yourClass", "unexpected exception", e);
```

What you are currently doing is logging `e.toString()` which doesn't include the full stacktrace.